# Counta unique string on filtered list

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I'd like to count unique string values on a filtered list (For example, the value should be 3 in this screenshot):

[image]

How can this be done in google sheets?

Here's the spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you will need a helper column with **`SUBTOTAL`** to evaluate hidden rows
- expand/cancel your filter
- paste this in **C3** cell and drag down:

  ```
  =SUBTOTAL(103, B3)
  ```
- then paste this into **B1** cell:

  ```
  =COUNTA(IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER(B3:B, C3:C=1))))
  ```

  [image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Use UNIQUE to get a list of unique values then COUNTA to count those values. You could even nest them:

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(B3:B))
```